# How to send data along with file in http POST (angularjs + expressjs)?

Tags: angularjs, express, multer

### Situation

I implemented file uploading. Front-end code is taken from popular [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_upload_file.htm). I send POST in service:

```
myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
             transformRequest: angular.identity,
             headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        
        .success(function(){
        })
       
        .error(function(){
         });
        }
    }]);
```

Typical multer usage in back-end:

```
exports.postFile = function (req, res) {

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, '../documents/')
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.originalname)
        }
    });

    var upload = multer({ //multer settings
        storage: storage
    }).single('file');

    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({error_code: 1, err_desc: err});
            return;
        }
        res.json({error_code: 0, err_desc: null});
    })

};
```

That works.

### Question

How to send some data in the same POST, let say string `"additional info"`?

#### What I tried

I tried to add data in service, i.e.:

```
...
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', file);
fd.append('model', 'additional info');

$http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {...})
```

It seems to be sent, but I don't know how to receive it in back-end. Tried to find it in `req` (without success).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To send data (i.e. json) and file in one POST request add both to form data:

```
myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);

        var info = {
            "text":"additional info"
        };
        fd.append('data', angular.toJson(info));

        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
             transformRequest: angular.identity,
             headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })

        .success(function(){
        })

        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}]);
```

On server side it's in `req.body.data`, so it can be received i.e. like this:

```
upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        res.json({error_code: 1, err_desc: err});
        return;
    }

    console.log(req.body.data);

    res.json({error_code: 0, err_desc: null});
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer. solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file from req.files and save it with fs.writeFile.

```
fs.readFile(req.files.formInput.path, function (err, data) {
  fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
    if (err) {
    throw err;
    }
    console.log("File Uploaded");
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't have any problems with sending end receiving files. It works. I want to send  (and receive) additional data (along with file) in the same POST request.

Comment: You can use the data property in your $http.post to send an object with all additional data that you want, sending all inputs.

Comment: i have modified the first answer showing how to pass data from all inputs, assuming you have a ng-model="user.email" etc on your input file.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
          $http({
                url: url, 
                method: 'POST',
                data: json_data,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
          }).then(function(response) {
                var res = response.data;
                console.log(res);
          }, function errorCallback(response) {
              // called asynchronously if an error occurs
             // or server returns response with an error status.
          });
```

Or just add the data property to your function.

```
    var userObject = {
    email: $scope.user.email,
    password: $scope.user.password,
    fullName: $scope.user.fullName
    };

    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
         transformRequest: angular.identity,
         data: userObject,
         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    })
```

You can try something like this on the backend.

```
req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log(chunk);
});
```

Comment: Where is file in this POST?

Comment: You said some string data.

Comment: I mean string along with file, as title says.

Comment: Regarding last edit: why should I look for it in server response?

Comment: Sorry. Is req.on. I will change that. Take a look at the second answer. Hope this help!