# Send string data and files via a single endpoint to a spring based server

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript, file-upload

I have a Spring based endpoint:

```
  @PostMapping("/new")
  public ResponseEntity house(@RequestBody Map<String ,Object> data) {
    data.values().forEach(System.out::println); 
    return ResponseHub.defaultFound("");
  }
```

I simply want to send a file along with some data. I'm using Ionic with Angular, so in angular I have:

```
  let map = new TSMap();
    map.set('field1', 'wan');
    map.set('field2', 'two');
    this.files = event.target.files;
    map.set('files', this.files);
    let data = map.toJSON();
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    };
    let url = "http://localhost:8080/api/data";
    this.http.post<HttpResponse>(url, data, httpOptions).pipe().toPromise().then(response=>{
      console.log(response);
    });
```

Sadly the output I get on my backend is just

```
wan
two
{0={}}
```

I know it's because I have Content-Type set to `application/json` in the http request I have on Angular. I've looked here and there, I've found a solution but allows uploading a single file and I won't be able to add any other data along with it. What would be the best solution?

**Edit:**
The html that calls the function that contains the Angular code:

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label id="profile_image" stacked>Select File</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="file" accept=".png, .jpg" multiple (change)="selectFile($event)">
      Select Image
    </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

This is where it gets the files from.

**Suggested Solution:**
I tried using `FormData`

```
  selectFile(event) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    let map = new TSMap();
    map.set('field1', 'wan');
    map.set('field2', 'two');
    let data = map.toJSON();
    formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(data));
    this.files = event.target.files;
    formData.append('files', this.files);
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      })
    };
    let url = "http://localhost:8080/api/data";
    this.http.post<HttpResponse>(url, formData, httpOptions).pipe().toPromise().then(response=>{
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

Backend:

```
  @PostMapping("/data")
  public ResponseEntity house(@RequestPart(name = "data") Map<String, Object> data,
                              @RequestPart(name = "files") MultipartFile[] files) throws IOException {
    data.values().forEach(System.out::println);
    for (MultipartFile file: files)
      System.out.println(file.getInputStream().available());
    return ResponseHub.defaultFound("");
  }
```

Now it just gives me this error:

> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the
>   request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

Comment: Are you trying to send file names or files themselves in 'file' field?

Comment: I'll add the html that calls that invokes that

Comment: That doesn't answer my question)

Comment: @RigoSarmiento : You wanna send post request with file and other input fields ?

Comment: @Naya since it's from the file selector of the html, it's the files themselves. I've checked.

Comment: @GovindParashar Yes, basically.

Comment: Great!
Then you should use FormData for sending any files to server. Please have a look at https://shazwazza.com/post/uploading-files-and-json-data-in-the-same-request-with-angular-js/

Comment: I've seen formData. But I also want to send other info along with the request such as a simple string or number.

Comment: @RigoSarmiento : Yes you can with formData . i.e var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);

        var info = {
            "field1":"one","field2":"two"
        };
        fd.append('data', angular.toJson(info));

Comment: @GovindParashar I gave that a go, I've added what happened to the question above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send data along with file in http POST (angularjs + expressjs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40773641/how-to-send-data-along-with-file-in-http-post-angularjs-expressjs)

Comment: @RigoSarmiento : set header 'Content-Type' : undefined